# Why I get -1 from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures

I use SQL Server 2012 and Entity Framework6.

I created table valued parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE IdArray AS TABLE 
(
     Id int
);
```

And here my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TEST_TLP]
    @List dbo.IdArray READONLY 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM Clients 
    WHERE Clients.Id IN (select Id from @List)
END
```

From Visual Studio I call stored procedure and passing paramaters to stored procedure.

I do it this way:

Create DataTable:

```
 var myDataTable = new DataTable();
 myDataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));

 myDataTable.Rows.Add(1);
 myDataTable.Rows.Add(3);
 myDataTable.Rows.Add(6);
```

Creating `SqlParameter` from DataTable:

```
 SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
 parameter.ParameterName = "@List";
 parameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
 parameter.TypeName = "dbo.IdArray";
 parameter.Value = myDataTable;
```

Fire stored procedure and passing parameter:

```
 var data = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SP_TEST_TLP @List", parameter);
```

The problem is that `ExecuteSqlCommand` returns `-1`.

Why `ExecuteSqlCommand` returns `-1` while I expect rows from database?

**Update:**

Change this row : WHERE Clients.Id IN ( '@List' )

To this: WHERE Clients.Id IN (select Id from @List)

Comment: Perhaps you need `_context.Database.SqlQuery<YourTypedRow>("SP_TEST_TLP @List", parameter)` instead

Comment: `ExecuteSqlCommand` returns an int, which is the return value of the procedure call. This is not the rowset, which is transported differently (for example to `SqlDataAdapter`, `SqlDataReader`, or in your case perhaps `DataTable` via `ExecuteDataTable`

Comment: Also, your `WHERE Clients.Id IN ( '@List' )` should be `WHERE Clients.Id IN (select id from @list)`

Comment: If you are calling a proc `-1` is by design.  it will be the number of rows modifed by `insert, update, delete` or `-1` if the called action is a proc.

Comment: Since this is a table valued parameter why not use join? SELECT * 
    FROM Clients c
 join @List l on l.Id = c.Id

Comment: Aside from the current issue you should consider not using the sp_ prefix. I prefer no prefixes as they don't add anything other than extra keystrokes. But for performance you should not use that prefix. It is reserved by MS and can cause all sorts of issues. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Now that I read @Sean Lange's comment I see your real problem.  You are looking for a `Clients.Id` that equals `"@List"`.  Change this to either a join or a sub query to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExecuteSqlCommand returns an int and is meant for action queries (Insert, Update) and returns the number of row affected by a single nonquery.
Try ExecuteDataTable or something like that for results.

Here's a good example:
 [Retrieve a DataTable using a SQL Statement](http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/dal-retrieve-a-datatable-using-a-sql-statement/)

Answer (score 3):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Yes, this is ADO.Net but this is the underlying code.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

BTW... you have a bug in your stored proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_TEST_TLP] -- don't use SP_
    @List dbo.IdArray READONLY 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM Clients 
    WHERE Clients.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @list) -- use subquery

    /* or a join
    SELECT * 
    FROM Clients 
    INNER JOIN @list I ON Clients.Id = I.Id
    */
END
```